# How to mock async response

Tags: python, mocking, python-asyncio, python-unittest, aiohttp

I'm trying to test an async request but I didn't find how to do. I tried with patch decorator, with AsyncMock... Everytime, I had either *aexit error* or *AsyncMock can't be used in await expression*... Where am I wrong ?

```
class RequestService:
    async def requestPostPicture(self, session: aiohttp.ClientSession, photoData: dict):
        try:
            with aiohttp.MultipartWriter('form-data') as mpwriter:
                part = mpwriter.append(photoData['file'][1],{'content-type': photoData['file'][2]})
                part.set_content_disposition('form-data', name='file', filename=photoData['file'][0])
            async with session.post('https://www.api-url.com', data=mpwriter, headers=self.headers) as resp:
                if isinstance(resp, dict):
                  return resp
                apiResponse = await resp.json
                return apiResponse
        except Exception as error:
            return {'error': str(error)}
```

My test :

```
class TestRequestService(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    @patch('aiohttp.ClientSession.post')
    async def testRequestPostPictureDict(self, mockPost):
        mockPost.__aenter__.return_value = {"error": "test"}
        requestservice = RequestService()
        pictureTest = {'file': ('photodatatest.jpg', 'photodatatest', 'image/jpeg')}
        connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=15)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as sessionPicture:
            returnValue = await requestservice.requestPostPicture(sessionPicture, pictureTest)
        self.assertEqual(returnValue, {'error': 'test'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async def testRequestPostPictureDict(self):
        mock = aiohttp.ClientSession
        mock.post = MagicMock()
        mock.post.return_value.__aenter__.return_value = {'error': 'test'}
```